# Display uploaded image from target web-resources

Tags: java, spring, servlets, primefaces

I uploaded image via Android Device to localhost:8082, image was saved in "/noteProject/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/bg.png", and I dont know how to display it.

When I go to http:// localhost:8082/noteProject/resources/bg.png in browser, it's ok.

I would like display it with primefaces.

Before I had this for test. Folder media was inside webapp folder (webapp/media).

```
<p:graphicImage value="/media/images/tat.jpg"
            alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}" />
```

Can somebody tell me how I should change the path?

I have dynamic web project with spring, hibernate, primefaces.(sorry for my english).

Comment: how did you do the upload, did you use the primefaces upload widget?

Comment: You shouldn't try this approach. Ideally , have a database with a table to save the image. Use your Android device to save to database and display the image from database in your web application.

Comment: @jhadesdev I have Servlet to upload, not primefaces upload widget [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093740/android-upload-a-file-in-the-tomcat-server). I will also upload file like mp3 or 3gp, should I save it to database?

Comment: edit, now I save the file into C:/var. But I cant show to server where  the image is. I added to server.xml <Context path="/noteProject/images" docBase="/var" /> but I get error:  Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base C:\INZ\work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\var does not exist or is not a readable directory